# Is the use of "all set" correct in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is the context:

> The rules of playing cricket are very easy. All you need to do is
>   follow my instructions. Get the bat and ball from the storeroom and we
>   are all set.

But this doesn't sound quite correct to me. I am getting the that feeling I need to add "to go" in the end.

> The rules of playing cricket are very easy. All you need to do is
>   follow my instructions. Get the bat and ball from the storeroom and we
>   are all set **to go.**

Is the first sentence correct or is it necessary to add "to go" in the end? What grammatical difference does adding "to go" make?

Comment: Nothing. The first version is preferable, since it is shorter.

Comment: Yeah, either is perfectly "legal", but the added "to go" is annoyingly redundant.

Comment: Don't forget to fix your first sentence (it should be "are" instead of "is" because you are talking about rules, which is plural).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with both of those sentences. "All set" in this context fills in the use of "to go" but does not make the sentence improper if you use it.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. This site strives to provide objective answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective and could be improved by adding [references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/59/77227). Take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about good answers.